# What should one know about term logic before studying propositional and predicate logic?

Tags: logic

I'm hearing that predicate logic replaces term logic, but teaching of predicated logic assumes knowledge of term logic. What are essential to know from term logic before studying propositional and predicate logic?

Comment: You don't have to know anything about term logic. A lot of introductory courses in logic don't even teach it.

Comment: What replaces term logic is just a simple fragment of the predicate calculus, the [monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus), it is something of a 1-1 translation. So if you learn predicate calculus independently and then want to understand what the term logic is about this is one way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're seeking an understanding of the *history and philosophy  of logic*, you really should not need to know anything about term logic to study propositional or predicate logic itself. Certainly the way propositional and predicate logic are standardly taught is self-contained. You may begin with some intuitive syllogisms, but ultimately you don't need to know anything deep about Aristotle's logic to learn modern predicate logic. There are plenty of high-quality free resources, e.g., http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/tecb2/forallx.shtml